# Why is this inclusion map continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, lp-spaces

If $1\le p<q<r\le\infty$, then I want to conclude that the inclusion map $L^p\cap L^r\to L^q$ is continuous, But I have seen this reference [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion_map), but I think that I am not understanding the definition or I am missing something, because the inclusion map always seems to me continuos.

In my case the map will act as:

$$\iota: L^p\cap L^r\to L^q$$

$$\iota (f)=f$$

where on $L^p\cap L^r$ we use the norm $\|\cdot\|_p + ||·||_r$.

So then can someone help me to prove the above result in a better way?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: What norm did you put on $L^p\cap L^r$ (continuity is a topological property, so we need a topology).

Comment: Well is the $ ||•||_p$ norm :)

Comment: That is not obvious from what you have written. It could be the $\|\cdot\|_r$ norm. Please edit accordingly.

Comment: Ok, sorry I have understand your point, you need a norm of the intersection right?, so just a second :) please :)

Comment: Read below: the norm you want on $L^p \cap L^r$ is the norm $\|\cdot \|_p + \|\cdot\|r$

Comment: Right :), I was just trying to edit, sorry, I didn't read carefully your above comment :)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: What we need to prove to prove continuity of such inclusion map is that there exists a constant $C>0$ such that, for $f \in L^p \cap L^r$,
$$
\|f\|_q \leq C \|f\|,
$$

where $\|f\|=\|f\|_p + \|f\|_r$ is a norm on $L^p \cap L^r$.

Comment: No, I have just write the norm :), so Can you give a better explanation? :) Thanks in advance :).

Comment: Can that constant depend on $||\cdot||_r$ or exactly why does that prove that the inclusion map is continuos ?

Comment: No, it can't. For a linear operator between normed spaces being continuous is equivalent to being bounded. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_operator#Equivalence_of_boundedness_and_continuity).

Comment: So why I need to prove the inequality with the q norm ?

Comment: I do not understand your question. You have $\iota \colon (L^p\cap L^r, \|\cdot\|_p+\|\cdot\|_r) \to (L^q, \|\cdot\|_q)$, so on the LHS you'll have $\|\iota(f)\|_q=\|f\|_q$.

Comment: Right :) sorry :), so let figure out the answer, so I will edit my post, when I do that, Can you give your verification ?

Comment: Do **not** edit the post changing its original purpose. [Here](http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~jconder/real-analysis/ch6.pdf) is a solution (Problem 3, the very first one), so you can check your work with it.

Answer (score 1):

You want $i : L^p \cap L^r \to L^q$ to be continuous when you equip the domain with the $L^p$ norm and the domain with the $L^q$ norm. Since it is linear, it is equivalent for it to be bounded, i.e.

$$\| f \|_q \leq C \| f \|_p$$

for all $f \in L^p \cap L^r$. This is actually *not* true. Here's a proof.

Suppose $f \in L^p \setminus L^q$, without loss of generality assume $f \geq 0$. Let $f_n(x) = \min \{ f(x),n \}$. Then $f_n \in L^p \cap L^\infty$ hence $f_n \in L^q$. You want your inequality to hold for all $f_n$. Thus we should be able to take limits on both sides...but then we conclude

$$\infty \leq C \| f \|_p$$

which is not true.

On the other hand, one can equip $L^p \cap L^r$ with the norm $\| f \| = \| f \|_p + \| f \|_r$. Then the inequality is perhaps the simplest possible *interpolation inequality*; cf. https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/03/30/245c-notes-1-interpolation-of-lp-spaces/

Comment: I now believe the norm that OP wants on $L^p \cap L^r$ is the sum of the two norms. Sorry I wasn't paying enough attention to it before. :)

Comment: @SilviaGhinassi Now that would make more sense.

Comment: I'm sure OP was just confused about what norm to use. Thanks for pointing it out, anyway.

Comment: Just give a second to check that web page :)

Comment: Sorry, where exactly is the part you want me to look at?

Comment: @user162343 I think Lemma 9 is a sharper version of the bound you want.

Comment: Ok, let me check it, If I have further questions, can I let you know?

Comment: @user162343 Sure. By the way, an alternate, less "hard analysis" approach here is to notice that if the inclusion map were continuous on $L^p \cap L^r$, then by density it could be extended to all of $L^p$. But there are $L^p$ functions which are not $L^q$...